# knockout.utils.arrayForEach not working?

Tags: knockout.js

Can anyone explain why this doesnt work?

```
function MyViewModel() {
    var data = [
        { forename: "Bob", age: 23 }, 
        { forename: "Alex", age: 19 }, 
        { forename: "Joe", age: 67 }
    ];
    var persons = ko.observableArray(data);
    useForEach = function () {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(persons, function (item) {
            item.age(99);
        });
    };

    return {
        persons: persons,
        useForEach: useForEach
    }
}

var vm = new MyViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

I am hoping age is updated on my view but nothing happens....here's my view:

```
<button data-bind="click: useForEach ">useForEach</button>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Forename</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: persons">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: forename"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: age"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should unwrap `observableArray` to access the array. Also the age property is not observable so you cannot assign value to it in such a way. You should either convert it to an observable or assign the value using `=`.

```
useForEach = function () {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(persons(), function (item) {
        item.age = 99;
    });
};
```

I suggest to add a separate class for 'person' where all properties are observables:

```
function Person(name, age){
    var self = this;

    self.forename = ko.observable(name);
    self.age = ko.observable(age);
}    

function MyViewModel() {
    var data = [new Person("Bob", 23), new Person("Alex", 19), new Person("Joe", 67)];
    var persons = ko.observableArray(data);
    useForEach = function () {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(persons(), function (item) {
            item.age(99);
        });
    };

    return {
        persons: persons,
        useForEach: useForEach
    }
}
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hn5we/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here the main difference is that in this case we are making an `observableArray` of `ko.observables` and in the question you were making just an `observableArray`. Knockout documentation also stress this point.

> **Key point: An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array,
>   not the state of those objects**
>
> Simply putting an object into an observableArray doesn’t make all of
>   that object’s properties themselves observable. Of course, you can
>   make those properties observable if you wish, but that’s an
>   independent choice. An observableArray just tracks which objects it
>   holds, and notifies listeners when objects are added or removed.

Try this

```
function Person(fn, age){
    var self = this;
    self.forename = ko.observable(fn);
    self.age = ko.observable(age);
}
var data = [
    { forename: "Bob", age: 23 }, 
    { forename: "Alex", age: 19 }, 
    { forename: "Joe", age: 67 }
];   
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var personArray = [];
    for(var i=0;i<data.length; i++){
        personArray.push( new Person(data[i].forename, data[i].age));
    }
    self.persons = ko.observableArray(personArray);
    self.useForEach = function () {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.persons(), function (item) {
            item.age(99);
        });
    };
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/wqmff/